# RTK query is looping over result but not providing the expected content

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm currently doing the Redux Essentials tutorial and stuck in [chapter 7](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics#displaying-posts-with-queries):
When switching from the classical thunk to the `RTK query`, the mapping will not work:

```
content = posts.map(post => <PostExcerpt key={post.id} post={post} />)
```

The error message is:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
```

To find the reason, I've broken the code down to something simple as follows:

```
} else if (isSuccess) {
    content = '';
    //content = posts.map(post => <PostExcerpt key={post.id} postId={post}/>);
    if (posts !== undefined) {
        for (const post1 in posts)
            if (post1 !== undefined) content +=
                ' loop: ' + post1.toString() + ' typ: ' + typeof(post1) + ' ID: ' + post1.title + '!!';
            else content += 'kein post';
    }
```

The output of my curious code is:

`loop: 0 typ: string ID: undefined!! loop: 1 typ: string ID: undefined!! loop: 2 typ: string ID: undefined!!`

So it is looping but not having the right values in the variable. This is weird as the posts variable seems to have the right content. Here is the output of the evaluation:

[image: Evaluation of "posts" variable]

Opening the [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux-essentials-example-app/tree/checkpoint-5-createApi/?from-embed) at the end of the mentioned tutorial page also does not render the posts - so there might be a bug somewhere.

As I didn't find any similar problem description, I hope, you may give me a hint of what is wrong.

Comment: Can you guide me where do I find the piece of code which is shared in the question in the codesandbox?

Comment: The cited source in the Sandbox is under
src/features/posts/PostsList.js in line 51

Answer (score 0):

It is running now without problem. To be honest, I unfortunately do not know, why.
Can't find any difference in my code history, which might allow to recognize, what happend. Bizarre...